# Display a Twitter feed in Ionic APP

Tags: angularjs, twitter, ionic-framework

The Situation:

I want to display a Twitter feed from a twitter website I do not own, for example the NY Times https://twitter.com/nytimes.

So I dont need any Logins or Authentications just a Simple twitter feed. So when I press on a tweet it redirects me to the original tweet on twitter.

I could not find any solution for that while reading the twitter api documentation.

Answer (score 0):

This plugin might be a good starting point:

https://github.com/drrasic/ionic_twitter_feed